# specs2 containTheSameElementsAs does not work when parameter is java.util.List

Tags: scala, specs2, scala-java-interop

What do I need to do to pass in containTheSameElementsAs as the argument for a java.util.List parameter

For example:

```
 class Foo() {
   void javaList(List<Bar> bars) = ???
 }
```

Running a specs2 SpecificationWithJunit Test with the following code:

```
 val foo = mock[Foo]
 ...
 got {
    one(foo).javaList(containTheSameElementsAs(SOME_LIST))
 }
```

Right now I'm getting the error:

found   : org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[Traversable[Bar]]

required: java.util.List[Bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "adapt" the matcher to become a `Matcher[java.util.List[Bar]]`, like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

class Foo {
  def javaList(bars: java.util.List[Int]) = bars
}

val foo = mock[Foo]

foo.javaList(java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2))

got {
   one(foo).javaList(containTheSameElementsAs(Seq(1, 2)) ^^ ((_: java.util.List[Int]).toList))
}
```

The `((_: java.util.List[Int]).toList)` part transforms the matcher argument so that it has the type expected by the matcher.

Comment: what if I want to use be_==(1) as an argument for an int method parameter?

Comment: I see. This is because `be_==` is a `Matcher[Any]` while `be_===` is a `Matcher[T]`